# Examples of functions where $f'(x)=f(f(x))$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for examples of functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where $f'(x)=f(f(x))$ for all $x$. The only example I can find is the trivial one where f is identically 0.

Comment: Where did this problem come up? Are you looking for all such functions or just some nontrivial examples?

Comment: You can get some complex functions of the form $\alpha x^\beta$ that satisfy this condition.

Comment: @Carl it's a curiosity of mine. I just want some examples. I can't find any. Determining all such functions would be nice but perhaps too ambitious. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Theo Indeed, I also found this. But I am just interested in real valued functions.

Comment: Find $f$ is equivalent to solve the constrained variational problem: $$ \min_{y=f(x)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}(f'(x)-f(y))^2 dx dy $$  Good luck! ;)

Comment: @Alex Is this an open problem?

Comment: @user1488 I have no idea! I have just reformulated the problem to drop the composition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been solved [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h321705):

> **Result:** for every $a > 0$, there exists a unique differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(-a)=-a$ and $f' = f \circ f$.